# Intermittent erro using mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm having an error when using mongo with springboot, when trying to delete collections.

This error occurs intermittently, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I'm usingo mongo gcp, version 4.4.13, with replica.

**spring-boot version:** 2.3.1

**java version:** 1.8

**data.mongodb.uri:** ${mongodb.host}t2b_sale?retryWrites=true&w=majority

```
public void deleteLastVersion(String uuidOrganization, String uuidCampaign) {
    String collectionName = getName(uuidOrganization, uuidCampaign, false);
    mongoTemplate.dropCollection(collectionName);
    return;
}
```

Log error:

```
2022-04-23 08:40:56.269  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#5-1-C-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Got socket exception on connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:198632}] to thanos-shard-00-01.h07ky.mongodb.net:27017. All connections to thanos-shard-00-01.h07ky.mongodb.net:27017 will be closed.
2022-04-23 08:40:56.270  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#5-1-C-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:198632}] to thanos-shard-00-01.h07ky.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception sending message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
2022-04-23 08:40:56.272  INFO 1 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary thanos-shard-00-01.h07ky.mongodb.net:27017
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:133)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2863)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:568)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doRemove(MongoTemplate.java:1712)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.remove(MongoTemplate.java:1678)
at com.br.t2b.mercedeshitledengine.repository.BaseRepository.deleteLastVersion(BaseRepository.java:50)
at com.br.t2b.mercedeshitledengine.repository.BaseRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a40ae7c.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:550)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:432)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:272)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:256)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:500)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:429)
... 62 more
```

Comment: Here is a post with similar issue and a possible solution: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/exception-sending-message-mongosocketwriteexception/147517/2